# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/font/fontello.woff")

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, stylesheet, passenger, production

Good afternoon, I'm preparing a server under linux + apache + passenger + rvm + rails 4 in production, the problem I present is for the icons look, the first problem already surpassed that was to take the styles css is I resolved by enabling:

# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
   config.assets.compile = true

# Generate digests for assets URLs.
   config.assets.digest = true

in the / config / enviroments / production.rb

yet it still has the problem of icons, reference these are in the following path:

/ project / app / assets / stylesheets / fontello /

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem properly its the same issue I was facing while back. I fixed my problem by changing `/app/assets/stylesheets/icons.css` file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icons';
  src: url('../font/icons.eot?26481838');
  src: url('../font/icons.eot?26481838#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../font/icons.woff?26481838') format('woff'),
       url('../font/icons.ttf?26481838') format('truetype'),
       url('../font/icons.svg?26481838#icons') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I removed the `"../"` from beggining of each line so the it would look like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icons';
  src: url('font/icons.eot?26481838');
  src: url('font/icons.eot?26481838#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('font/icons.woff?26481838') format('woff'),
       url('font/icons.ttf?26481838') format('truetype'),
       url('font/icons.svg?26481838#icons') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just checking in in 2017. This fix didn't work for me, will report back when I find out what did.